# NGINX показать index.html из другого каталога

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильнее сделать в данной ситуации:

Есть куча проектиков со статикой, которые лежат по адресам cо случайными именами, например:

```
example.com/ertertert
example.com/y4re
example.com/rertrt35
example.com/erterjegeg
```

В корне каждого проекта лежит файл index.html

Нынешний единый конфиг для всех проектов такой:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Как средствами NGINX сделать так, чтобы при запросах вида

```
example.com/erterjegeg/asasdf/we234rew/sd342fs/edfsd42
В общем виде 
example.com/erterjegeg/(.*)$
```

отображать index.html из каталога example.com/erterjegeg , но при этом не делать rewrite урла в адресной строке?

Видимо, должно быт ьчто-то вроде

```
location /erterjegeg {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /erterjegeg/index.html;
}
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы вместо erterjegeg поставить переменную, так как сайтов куча и они постоянно генерируются?

Comment: `location / { root /путь/к/папке/example.com; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/ {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.html;
}
```

Это решение